# Validating tinyMce content

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I'm having a tinyMCE editor in an MVC view. The problem is I can't validate the contents of the editor, since the value of the textarea that it writes content is never empty, containing HTML always. I found an article here on the subject from were I took this:

```
tinyMCE.get('details').getContent()
```

I made some jquery javascript functions to validate the text area:

```
function detailsValid() {
    return tinyMCE.get('details').getContent().length > 0;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    onsubmit = function () {
        if (!detailsValid)
        {
            $("#validation").val("Please enter details");
        }
    }
})
```

'details' is the id of the textarea tinyMCE writes to.
The problem is that detailsValid function doesn't seem to fire (I checked using Chrome devTools). Any idea why this is happenning or an alternative way to validate tinyMCE editor contents greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have validators on underlying tinyMCE fields working no problem.

Comment: wher do you call onsubmit ?

Comment: @GrantThomas, could you please show me a working sample of one of your validations for tinyMCE ?

Comment: @Thariama, I have a submit button on the page;

Comment: Using ASP.NET, I simply have a `TextBox` with `TextMode="MultiLine"` and a `RequiredFieldValidator` applied to the field.

Comment: @GrantThomas, I'm using MVC... I tried using default validators (DataAnnotations), but didn't work

Comment: Is this your actual code? If not, please post an example showing your problem to jsfiddle.net. If so, you are not calling `detailsValid`, since you left out the braces, and your function is just assigned to a variable `onsubmit`.